# MySql Query Running in localhost but not in the Web Server

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database table something like this...

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `example` (
  `id` varchar(78) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(78) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(78) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `reg_date` date NOT NULL,
  `reg_time` time NOT NULL,
  `permission` varchar(78) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;
```

Now I am performing a query from PHP is ...

```
INSERT INTO `example` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `reg_date`, `reg_time`, `permission`) VALUES ('j652hsL', 'example_user', 'secret', '', '', '');
```

This query is running Perfectly in my localhost with a warning of course but not problem in data insertion... Yes the `reg_date`, `reg_time` & `permissions` fields are holding `0000-00-00`, `00:00:00`& `*Blank*` respectively...But there is no problem with Insertion... Now this same Insertion Query is not running on a certain Web Server...
I have a web server and I tested it there it was running with no Error but When I shifted to different Web Server it wasn't running there... I think its a some kind of Server settings issue... But What possibly could stop it from inserting the Data?

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: do you have necessary permissions for executing queries on the mysql server

Comment: Why don't you write what that warning is you get? And what error does that mysql server give where the question does not execute? Or are we meant to _guess_ that?

Comment: Is any other query working? The connection is successful?

Comment: Yes... I have necessary permissions actually when I write the query like this... `INSERT INTO `example` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `reg_date`, `reg_time`, `permission`) VALUES ('j652hsL', 'example_user', 'secret', '0000-00-00', '00:00:00', 'read');`

Comment: Yes the connection is successful... If I don't put the `permissions` value it says there is no Default value set for permissions and when I don't put anything in the `reg_date` & `reg_time` it says syntax error... Date & Time format incorrect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your local server and the web server uses different [`SQL MODE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html). Depending on how strict the mode is it handles zero-dates, default values and other things differently.

To get the current setting run `show variables like 'sql_mode'` on both servers.

Comment: Yes... The old server and the localhost has... sql_mode :
NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION